# youtube play button in place of circle play buttom

Tags: html, svg, icons

I have svg that contain circle button. I want youtube play button here

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="64" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-play-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><polygon points="10 8 16 12 10 16 10 8"></polygon></svg>
```

I want youtube play button here

Currently showing icon like this : https://prnt.sc/ir9UDBOZ0Vcc

I want like this: https://prnt.sc/EsHGJjWa8Lxg

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can always fill the empty space with a color like `fill='#fff'`

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="64" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-play-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><polygon points="10 8 16 12 10 16 10 8" fill='#fff'></polygon></svg>
```

Try this , not sure if this is what you want